# Control Textboxes (enable/disable) with radio buttons - jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, radio-button

I would like to get help with controlling textboxes, enable / disable, depending on selected radio button - jQuery would be preferable.

If a radio button is selected the associated textboxes will be enabled - others will be disabled. Same thing for all scenarios. One radio button will be pre selected.

Here is my markup:

> ```
>      <div>
>             <h1>Control fields</h1>
>             <div id="Div1">
>                 <div id="first">
>                     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" checked="checked" />First</br>
>         <input type="text" id="txt_one" /></br>
>         <input type="text" id="txt_two" /></br>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="second">
>                     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />Second</br>
>                     <input type="text" id="three" /></br>
>       <input type="text" id="txt_four" /></br>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <div id="third">
>                     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" checked="checked" />First</br>
>         <input type="text" id="txt_five" /></br>
>         <input type="text" id="txt_six" /></br>
>         <input type="text" id="txt_seven" /></br>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
> ```

Here is a link to: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDcH/1/

Comment: Could you show us some things you have tried?

Comment: @Kenneth all ive done is playing around in fiddler without no success. If I had something to "work" with i would have pasted it. Im still confused if i should go with divs(ids) or if i should work with childs (like a table markup).

Comment: Well, instead of showing a complete html-page, please show us a concrete example and some things you have tried (with or without success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have what you're looking for. Here is the jQuery:

```
$('.RadioExample').not('.First').siblings().prop('disabled',true);

$('.RadioExample').on('click',function(){
    $('.RadioExample')
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled',true);

    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled',false);
});
```

To do this, you add a class `RadioExample` to each radio, and `First` to the first radio button. This disables all the siblings of the radio buttons after the first one (checked by default) on page load, and then on each click redisables all and enables the siblings for the one clicked.

[I've updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CDcH/2/) as well.

There are a couple of ways to do this (another way would be with classes added or removed), but this was the one that came to mind first.

Comment: Great! Thanks man! Exactly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use custom classes, your actual markup it's ok, so, give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        $("#content").find("input:text").attr("disabled",true);
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
            $(this).parent().find("input:text").attr("disabled",false);
    });
});
```

That function will update the inputs when a radio changes, so all will be disabled, then if the actual radio gets checked, it will enable all inputs in the same container.

Take a look at your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hyunkeln/9CDcH/3/